# Converting SQL to Joomla Syntax (set and update)

Tags: sql, database, joomla, sql-update

Ok so basically I need to convert this regular sql statement to the syntax joomla uses via 
https://api.joomla.org/11.4/Joomla-Platform/Database/JDatabaseQuery.html

here is my statement

```
    SET @myunsubid = (
    SELECT subid 
    FROM aqbi8_acymailing_subscriber s
    WHERE s.email = 'email@email.co.nz' 
    );

SELECT @myunsubid;

UPDATE aqbi8_acymailing_listsub a
SET a.`status` = 1
WHERE a.subid = @myunsubid AND a.listid = 232
```

So id like it to be like

```
    $db->set(@myunsubid = ( $db->select($db->quoteName('subid') )
                        $db->from($db->quoteName('aqbi8_acymailing_subscriber s') )
                        $db->where($db->quoteName('s.email') = 'email@email.co.nz') 
                    )
$db->update($db->quoteName('aqbi8_acymailing_listsub a'))
$db->set($db->quoteName('a.status') = 1)
$db->where ($db->quoteName('a.subid') = @myunsubid AND $db->quoteName('a.listid') = 232 )
```

But this isnt quite right. please help!

Comment: this is a very old thread, but nevertheless I thought I'd respond as there's a much safer way to do this, using the ACY Mailing API. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out got it to work like this.

```
$db = &JDatabase::getInstance($option);
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// make a variable for subID
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('subid')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('aqbi8_acymailing_subscriber'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('email') . " = '" . $email ."'");

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
$test = $db->loadObjectList();
print_r( $test );
$myid =  $test[0]->subid;


$query->clear();

// // Create Database query
$fields = $db->quoteName('status') . ' =  1';
$conditions = array(
    $db->quoteName('subid') . ' = ' . $myid, 
    $db->quoteName('listid') . ' = ' . $listid
);

// // update query
$query->update($db->quoteName('aqbi8_acymailing_listsub'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);


$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make two trips to the database, you can write a subquery into your UPDATE's WHERE condition (no mysql variables or table aliases are necessary).

Raw Query:

> ```
> UPDATE aqbi8_acymailing_listsub
> SET status = 1
> WHERE listid = 232
> AND subid = (
>       SELECT subid
>       FROM aqbi8_acymailing_subscriber
>       WHERE `email` = 'email@email.co.nz'
>     )
> ```

Tested Code:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
try {
    $subquery = $db->getQuery(true)
                   ->select('subid')
                   ->from('#__acymailing_subscriber')
                   ->where("email = 'email@email.co.nz'");

    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->update("#__acymailing_listsub")
                ->set("status = 1")
                ->where(["listid = 232", "personid = ($subquery)"]);  // or make 2 where() calls

    echo $query->dump();  // if you want to see; *during development ONLY
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->execute();
    if ($affrows = $db->getAffectedRows()) {
        JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Updated.  Rows affected: $affrows", 'success');
    } else {
        JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Logic Error", 'error');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');  // never show getMessage() to public
}
```

It is not clear if any of your values are coming from users/untrusted sources, so be sure to follow good practices when writing variables into your queries -- like casting integers with `(int)` and calling `$db->quote()` on string values.

If you want to see a complex/convoluted UPDATE query with several other tables and techniques blended in, here is a comprehensive post: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22916/12352

Comment: I've necro-posted to show you a more refined technique and give you an answer to accept so that this page is deemed resolved.

Comment: Your profile is a bit thin.  Where in the world are you?  Are you a WordPress and Joomla developer?

Comment: Definitely advisable to use all of JDatabases escape/quote functions, regardless of the sources. That said, calling these functions through the API ensures that the model(s) sanitise all of the post data in any case ;)

Comment: Flooding the query builder method parameters with `q()` and `qn()` calls when there is no stability/security benefit is a strategy that many support because then "ignorant" devs don't need to think hard about what they are doing or why they are doing it.  I have a fair handle on this topic and I choose to omit the escaping calls when unnecessary so that my query is more concise, easier to read, and not making any unnecessary calls.  I am not going to call quoting/escaping methods on static strings, this is the point that I am making.

Answer (score 0):

### Please DON'T USE JDatabase Object to update Joomla tables, when there's an API available for the extension.

Whilst I appreciate the OP's question is pertaining to *how to update the joomla database using the **joomla database object (JDatabase)***, I propose a safer and more robust method, the "**ACYMailing API**".

### "BUT WHY?", I hear you ask...

**Good question!!!**
There are **2 pitfalls** in updating the joomla database directly - be it on the command-line, in a GUI such as MySQL Workbench or PHPMyAdmin, or even with the Joomla Database Object. Simply put, they both concern compatibility - 1. regarding third party integrations, and 2. concerning the future compatibility of your code. In a nutshell, whenever there's a an API for interacting with a component, I'd use it, over JDatabase every time to future proof your code, and ensure that all **pre** and **post** *save*, *update*, *delete*... ...*move*, and *publish* **plugin events** take care of your integrations, just as if you'd performed the *action* authentically.

*To elaborate on these points a bit...*

1. Most Joomla extensions (core and 3rd-party) make use of Joomla's powerful *plugin architecture*. By doing so, extensions can perform actions at key points in the application's life cycle.  For example, after *deleting a record* from a **table** belonging to *component1*, **delete** *related records* from a **table** relating to *compnent2*. Therefore, one run's the risk of **breaking** the behaviour/functionality of the component in question - *i.e. ACY Mailing*, as in your case.  Potentially, other core/3rd-party extensions that rely on ACY's data, that would otherwise, get updated through **onAfterSave()** or **onAfterDelete()** *plugin events*, as they **will not** get called.
2. There's a big risk that your code to break with future Joomla/ACY Mailing updates, if/when the table structure changes.

---

## OK, so how do we use the API?

The following example code displays everything that you should need to update a subscription record. Each step explains the code, which for reference, is summarised in doc and inline comments in the code itself. To begin, navigate to the file where you are entering your code, then...

## STEP BY STEP

**STEP 1:** Check the existence of ACY Mailing by attempting to include it's helper class, as follows. **N.B.** If the include_once() fails, you should see the echo statement, indicating that ACY Mailing **IS NOT** installed.

```
// load the ACY Mailing helper - bail out if not
if(!include_once(rtrim(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'components' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'com_acymailing' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'helpers' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'helper.php')){
    echo 'This code can not work without the AcyMailing Component';
    return false;
}
```

**STEP 2:** Set-up your parameters by inputting values into the following 3 variables. See examples in code comments.

```
// array    $lists  An array of integer IDs (primary keys) of the lists you want the user to be subscribed to (can be empty).    
//          e.g. array(2,4,6)
$lists      = array();

// array    $unsubs An array of integer IDs (primary keys) of the lists you want the user to be un-subscribed from (can be empty).
//          e.g. array(2,4,6)
$unsubs     = array(); 

// string   $userID Numeric Joomla User or user e-mail. For example: '42' or 'name@domain.com'
$userID     = '';
```

**STEP 3:** Add the following code to find the ACY Mailing user, from the Joomla User ID/Email address passed in to the ->subid() method, and bail out if not found.

```
// instantiate the ACY Mailing Subscriber (user) Class
$user = acymailing_get('class.subscriber'); 

// find the ACY Mailing user id (subid) from the joomla ID or email address set in $userID
$subID = $user->subid($userID);

// No ACY Mailing user/subscriber?
if(empty($subID))
    return; // bail out
```

**STEP 4:** Add the following code to check, and setup the data for any of the subscriptions/unsubscriptions you've configured to update ($lists and $unsubs arrays).  If any found, they will be updated.  If not found, return.

```
// create an array to store data in
$data = array();

// Set up new newsletter subscriptions from the $lists array()
if(!empty($lists)) foreach($lists as $listId)
    $data[$listId] = array("status" => 1);

// Set up un-subscriptions from the $unsubs array()
if(!empty($unsubs)) foreach($unsubs as $listId)
    $data[$listId] = array('status' => 0);

// no data, bail out...
if(empty($data)) 
    return; //there is nothing to do...

// update the user's subscription records, creating/removing subscriptions/unsubsriptions accordingly
$user->saveSubscription($subID, $data);
```

Comment: Since you are a Joomla specialist, please create a [joomla.se] Stack Exchange account and help us to resolve questions there.

Comment: Your https://www.joomla-guy-cardiff.uk/ page is down for maintenance (a plumber's house always has leaky pipes).  May I have a look at your LinkedIn page?  Are you part of a Meetup in the UK?  Joomla GitHub contributor?

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa, hehe! Yes, I've never really had to build my own site for development services, nor had time to, as despite doing this for nearly 11 years, it was always a side project.  Site will be done just as soon as I've got through client work. I don't use linked in sorry, but as soon as my site is done, I'll message you.